# jQuery combining functions

Tags: jquery

So, I have following functions:

```
function DIV(a,b){
   return '<div class="'+ a +'">'+ b +'</div>';
}
function IMG(a,b,c){
    return '<img class="'+ a +'" src="'+ b +'" alt="'+ c +'">';
}
function HREF(a,b,c){
    return '<a class="'+ a +'" href="'+ b +'">'+ c +'</a>';
}
function SPAN(a,b){
    return '<span class="'+ a +'">'+ b +'</span>';  
}
```

Is there a way to combine these functions to simplify them into one function.

Comment: Only if you also pass the tag type as an extra parameter and have a switch statement or dictionary of templates. What is the purpose of this code? Often knowing the problem you are trying to solve will result in better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a switch statement like this following example I've made to show you:

```js
function TestFunction(tag, a, b, c)
{
  switch (tag)
  {
      case "div":
      case "span": 
        return '<' + tag + ' class="'+ a +'">'+ b +'</' + tag + '>';
      break;
      
      case "img":
        return '<' + tag + ' class="'+ a +'" src="'+ b +'" alt="'+ c +'">';
      break;
                
      case "a":
        return '<' + tag + ' class="'+ a +'" href="'+ b +'">'+ c +'</a>';
      break;

      default:
          // Default value.
      break;
  }  
  
}

console.log(TestFunction("div", 1, 1, 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not match the original HTML generated in the OPs question. Each element has different parameters

Comment: I see. I am getting an idea of what can be done. Thanks for the advice thought!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I was giving him an idea of what could be done.

Comment: There ya go +1. What a great idea.. wish I'd though of it ;) Don't suppose you want to add the dictionary version too?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - When you typed out your comment, I was actually typing the answer out. You just beat me to it in the comment ;)

Comment: Comment... 10 seconds... answer 6 minutes later? I just would have preferred he explained the problem instead as this is not a great pattern to use (a template dictionary would be slightly "less bad", but still not great) :)

Comment: Just a quick question, is there a way to combine two `cases`? such as my `div` and `span` are identical. Something like `case ["span","div"]:`

Comment: @RyanPicard Check my updated answer, this is how you'd do it.